# (WordPress) How to use if OR if post?

Tags: php, if-statement

I want to show some HTML code for specific posts, so I put this on HEADER templete:

```
<?php if(is_single(24) || is_single(34)) { ?>
MY HTML CODES
<?php } ?>
```

I tried those too:

```
<?php if(is_single(24) && is_single(34)) { ?>
<?php if((is_single(24)) && (is_single(34))) { ?>
<?php if((is_single(24)) || (is_single(34))) { ?>
```

And its not working. If I put this code for single post, like this:

```
<?php if(is_single(24) { ?>
```

Its working well.. but I need to do that for many posts.

Comment: So you want to display some HTML for a set of posts?  How many?

Comment: in_array and list of posts?

Answer (score 2):

You could do if (is_single() && in_array($post->ID, array(24, 34)) {}

Depending on context, you may need to make $post global.

I'd probably add some metadata to the posts though and check for that instead... Less messy.

Comment: or even add an extra category name to those posts.  Probably more sustainable in the long run.  What happens when you want to add more posts that need html printout, six months from now?  The use of category names makes it way easy to filter and/or verify which posts get the extra work from the All post admin page.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `in_array`

```
<?php if(in_array(POST_ID, array(POST_IDS))) { ?>
MY HTML CODES
<?php } ?>
```